# What happened to this creeper? It seems to have a blueish glow

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I came across this: [image]

The creeper in the picture seems to be surrounded by a blue-ish glow.
What is it? I immediately left my world and came here. What does it do?

Comment: I don't understand this part: `When I immediately left my world and came here.`

Comment: @Nolonar I had no idea what to do about the crepper, so when I get the answer I will go back in and fight it (or run for my life)

Comment: Cleaned up a pile of comments - be civil, guys. Arguing in comments like this solves nothing. :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a Charged Creeper. It has been struck by lightning and is twice as dangerous than a regular Creeper. It will blow up a larger area and do more damage if you're unlucky enough to be near-by when it goes off.

The [Minecraft wiki page on Creepers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper#Charged_Creepers) has more technical details.

Answer (score 25):

The creeper in the picture is a Charged Creeper. It only appears when a creeper gets shocked by lightning. They have a larger explosion radius than regular Creepers.

If you can make it follow you next to another mob, then make it explode, the mob will drop his head, but only one mob head per Charged Creeper explosion.

Comment: Is the mob head a guaranteed drop?

Comment: Yes, but you can only get 1 mob head per charger creeper. So if there are 100 mobs in the range of a charged creeper and the charged creeper explodes, only 1 mob will drop their head. This only works for the hostile mobs and dosn't work for hostile bosses. (Ender Dragon and Wither)

Comment: Did not know that... That's really cool :)

Comment: It's best to put an array of holes with creepers on each hole and glass on top if them in the spawn chunk.

Comment: @LuisUllman If you want to create a farm that creates them, yes, but in this case the OP has found one in the wild.

Comment: It's extra tips. Extra is good... no?

Comment: @Luiyay Not all hostile mobs. Only Zombie, Skeleton and Creeper

Answer (score 0):

When creepers are struck by lightning, they will glow. This means that the creeper is super charged and will be more hostile, maybe enough to blow up a small house! When another mob is near by when a super charged creeper blows up, it has a 75.99% chance of dropping a skull, depending on what type of mob it is. A Player's 76.89% chance of dying of a creeper explosion increases to a 94.97% chance of dying when the creepers is charged. I can't guarantee anything else to happen when charged creepers are around, but I may have something to share soon, because I have been experimenting with charged creepers, and I've gotten results that hint others facts about charged creepers.

Answer (score -5):

It was struck by lightning, when it get struck by Lightning, i believe its called a Charged Creeper

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Although this is technically a valid answer, the downvotes are to the fact that there are already 2 answers with majour upvotes, you used grammer poorly, and used "i believe".